# Select each first record with id in another table's result

Tags: php, mysql, sql, greatest-n-per-group

I have two tables, `Users(id, username)` and `Posts(id, user_id, content)`. I want to list a summary of them which, I want to list all users and the first post of each user. How can I realize this in one query?

I tried something like.

### **QUERY**

```
SELECT Users.*, Posts.content 
FROM Users, Posts 
WHERE Posts.user_id=T_Users.id
```

But it will return all posts for each user (I cannot add `LIMIT 1` at the tail of course which only returns one user).

Some sample records:

Users table:

```
id   username
1    test1   
2    test2
```

Posts table:

```
id   user_id content
1    1       This is a test1's content.
2    1       This is another test1's content.
3    2       This is a test2's content.
```

And I want the result:

```
Users.id    Users.username    Posts.content
1           test1             This is a test1's content.
2           test2             This is a test2's content.
```

Comment: Please show us your table structure

Comment: @Ullas the structure is in the first sentence and I code-styled it now.

Comment: Please provide some sample data.

Comment: `MIN(id)` from `Posts` table and `GROUP BY user_id`.

Comment: Can you form the query as I am not quite familiar with advanced sql queries?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is one approach to get the latest record per user i assume the latest record will be considered as the minimum post id

```
SELECT u.*, p.content 
FROM Users u
join Posts p on p.user_id=u.id
join (select user_id ,min(id) id from Posts  group by user_id ) p1
on (p.id = p1.id and p.user_id = p1.user_id )
```

[`Demo`](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/90b1fb/1)

Comment: A little extension question: how can I add a WHERE clause for Users, e.g., "where Users.gender=1"? As I want to add a gender filter (the structure is thus (id, username, gender)).

Comment: OK, I change the first join clause to "join Posts p on p.user_id=u.id AND u.gender=1" and it seems working.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
select min(x.id) as Id,x.user_id,x.content from(
    select p.id,p.user_id,p.content from Users u inner join Posts p
    on u.id=p.user_id and u.gender=1
)x  group by x.user_id
```

Comment: Your sql seems faster. But the queried columns are not what I exactly want. Can you revise it to return (Users.id, Users.username, Poster.content)? Now you reduces one join and that may be the cause for faster speed. I will try it again.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried group by clause.

```
SELECT Users.*, Posts.content 
FROM Users, Posts 
WHERE Posts.user_id=T_Users.id GROUP BY Posts.user_id
```